# Find derivative of $4\cos(x - \frac{311\pi}{180})$

Tags: derivatives

> Find derivative of $4\cos(x - \frac{311\pi}{180})$

I think I should use the chain rule which states:

$h'(x) = g'(f(x)) \cdot f'(x)$

$g'(f(x)) = - 4 \sin(4\cos(x - \frac{311\pi}{180}))$

$f'(x) = x$

$h'(x) = 4 \sin x(4\cos(x - \frac{311\pi}{180}))$

Comment: The chain rule is $h′(x)=g′(f(x))f′(x)$. You have an extra $x$. You also need to define $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ so that $h(x)=g(f(x))=4\cos(x-\frac{311\pi}{180})$, rather than using the original function for both $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chain rule is:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}g(f(x))=g'(f(x)) f'(x)
$$

Here you need $f(x)=x-\frac{311}{180}\pi$ and $g(x)=4\cos(x)$, so the chain rule gives:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left[4 \cos\left(x-\frac{311}{180}\pi\right) \right]=-4\sin\left(x-\frac{311}{180}\pi \right) \times \frac{d}{dx}\left(x-\frac{311}{180}\pi \right)=-4\sin\left(x-\frac{311}{180}\pi \right)
$$

Comment: What is $f'(x)$ in this case?

Comment: @dagda1 it says in the answer: $f(x)=x-\frac{311}{180}\pi$